# How to filter linq query based on all of the values of one property from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below method:

```
    public static void UpdateKeySetToDatabase(List<TrackedKey> set)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var c = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                c.Open();

                //var result = c
                //.Where(x => x.Product.Any(p => p.ProductNumber == "11"))
                //.ToList();



                DataContext dc = new DataContext(c);

                Table<TrackedKey> tableKeys = dc.GetTable<TrackedKey>();

                var KeyStates =
                    from k in tableKeys
                    select k;

                foreach (var k in KeyStates)
                {
                    EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"Key last touch time {k}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventHandling.Logging.CreateTextEvent($"linq error {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

I want to produce the keyStates data based on only the keys in tableKeys which ALSO exist in the property 'keyId' of the passed in List set. How is this done? I've tried to look for answers on SO and other pages, but they seem to show examples where the List you want to filter on contains ONLY that one property, e.g. a list of Keyids only. My list is of the object TrackedKey, of which one of its properties is KeyId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var KeyStates = from k in tableKeys
                join s in set on k.keyId equals s.keyId
                select s;
```

OR (probably less efficient)

```
var KeyStates = tableKeys.Where(x => set.Any(y => y.keyId == x.keyId));
```